# Run time of the following code

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

So my code is

```
function mystery(n, k):
     if k ≥ n 
        return foo(n) 
    sum = 0 
    for i = k to n 
        sum = sum + mystery(n, k+1) 
    return sum
```

I have created a tree and the answer I am getting is $n^2*(n-1)!$. where foo is O(n. )Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  If you were to turn the recursion into iteration, you would have loops that run triangle(n-k) times -- where **triangle** is the triangle function, the sum of integers 1 through N.  The formula for that is

triangle(N) = N * (N-1) / 2

Multiply this by O(n), drop the 1/2 constant, and that yields your answer.

[ N.B. Since **k** is a constant for complexity purposes, you also drop that]

Comment: hi, I wrote n^2 * (n-1) factorial.  is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  My mistake; it's factorial (product 1 through n), rather than triangle (sum 1 through n).